# Senior Apple Customer Service Contact Required

Tags: itunes, apple-id, password

I’ve currently got an issue with Apple that issue being that I’m attempting to recover purchases that I’ve paid money to Apple for an Apple ID that I’ve forgotten the password to.

Unfortunately I cannot reset the password as I’ve got an outdated (and since removed) two step verification setup on the account, and I cannot locate the required recovery key to reset it.

All other reset options were taken away by Apple when two step verification is enabled. I’ve had several phone calls and online chats with Apple advisors, Senior advisors and iTunes Support and I keep getting told one of three things “sorry we need password verification to access the account” or “purchases can not be transferred to another Apple ID” or it’s an Apple “privacy” policy.

Whilst I reluctantly accept that I’m locked out and cannot regain access my account I do not accept that I have to readily forfeit everything that I’ve paid good money for to Apple for.

Apple unfortunately haven’t thought through the account recovery process for accounts with two step enabled properly and have in my opinion dropped the ball.

The only assistance I’ve received is an email from iTunes Support with a feedback link, I’ve chosen not to use this as it is exactly what is says “feedback” and Apple advise on the feedback page that they will not respond to individual comments. I actually want my case to be looked into and I want my primary Apple ID credited with everything I’ve paid for and I require a written response.

I previously asked an Apple advisor for a senior point of contact/department where I can take up my grievance and the only contact that they could give me was a surface mail address in another country, this is totally unacceptable especially for a technology company.

I’ve also been told by an Apple Senior Advisor that they can’t due to the way in which their system is engineered see an Apple ID’s details/history without an account holders password.

I’m located in Australia and I’m looking for contact details for an Apple Department that is capable of accessing Apple ID’s and seeing its history without a password being needed and has the authority to credit an account. Law enforcement agencies seem to get what they want without to much trouble and they don’t have passwords this according to the public disclosures on Apples Privacy webpage.

Apologies for rambling on, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ask apple for a refund or for them to deliver you a new password when you can’t or won’t follow their steps to reset the password on an AppleID?

Comment: It seems like you can [reset the password by email](https://support.apple.com/en-jo/HT201487#questions). I suppose you tried that? Did you loose access to your mail address?

Comment: Unfortunately reset by email, answering security questions or submit an account recovery request were all taken away by Apple when I enabled Two Step Verification. There are absolutely no options available for me to reset.

Comment: The site linked in my previous comment suggests otherwise. I just checked and wasn't offered any alternative method either. That is scary...

Answer (score 1):

Apple makes it easy to request legal access to things you can’t get when you can’t reset the password via normal channels.

- https://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/

If you’re not a lawyer or part of the government, you probably won’t get much help there. Same trying to get Apple support to disclose information or rescue an account if you can’t just follow the instructions for forgotten passwords / lock out.

Apple surely has their people trained and they know full well what you want and they are saying no. If you’ve been through 3 people, you’re not going to get a better audience by stalking / brow beating someone in my experience. Apple said no to the US FBI for unlocking phones and accounts, so they’re likely not going to cave with someone that’s not able to unlock purchases on their account.

Answer (score 1):

## Australian Competition & Consumer Commission

As you are in Australia, and assuming you made the purchases in Australia, contact the [Australian Competition & Consumer Commission](https://www.accc.gov.au):

> The ACCC promotes competition and fair trade in markets to benefit consumers, businesses, and the community. We also regulate national infrastructure services. Our primary responsibility is to ensure that individuals and businesses comply with Australian competition, fair trading, and consumer protection laws - in particular the Competition and Consumer Act 2010.

The ACCC is best placed to determine your rights and to help convince Apple of their responsibilities towards you.